# Splitting views into equal parts

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to design my layout as below. My current approach is to have a LinearLayout wrapping two other LinearLayouts. Each of these has `layout_weight=1`. Then the bottom layout wraps another two and each of those also has `layout_weight=1`. I've heard that nested weights is not advised - but is it? Otherwise, what would be a better alternative?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: In your case, nesting isn't such a big deal. You have a very few Layouts and it shouldn't affect performances in any way.

Comment: Should the `layout_width` for the "bottom" two views be `0dp` as well?

Comment: try `GridLayout`, there is also a compatibility lib for older android versions

Comment: The layout_**dimension** you want to fill in % has to be 0dp. So, layout_width for the 2 bottom views = 0dp. as well as the height for the two "outer" containers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be my approach:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:weightSum="2">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_weight="1">

        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="#ff00ff"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:weightSum="2"
                  android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="#ffff00"/>

        <View android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="#00ffff"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I believe weights might be "inefficient” because in order to apply them appropriately, a layout has to be measured first. If its children apply weights as well, it may lead to repeated measurements of same layouts, *potentially* hampering performance.

If your layout will be complex, you might want to consider alternative approaches (e.g. creating a custom `ViewGroup`), but remember:

> We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time:
>   premature optimization is the root of all evil.

so make sure you actually have a problem before trying to solve it.